# How to separate array items into separate columns in Spark?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, multiple-columns

```
+---------------------------+
|address                    |
+---------------------------+
|[San Jone, 19422, CA, 126]|
|[Queens, 11372, NY, 5543]  |
+---------------------------+
```

How do I separate one column into 4 if the value inside is in an array?

Expected Output:

```
+-----------------------------+
|city    | Zip  |state|street |
+-----------------------------+
|San Jose| 19422| CA  |126    |
|Queens  | 11372| NY  |5543   |
+-----------------------------+
```

EDIT:

```
 [
    {
        "firstName": "Rack",
        "lastName": "Jackon",
        "gender": "man",
        "age": 24,
        "address": {
            "streetAddress": "126",
            "city": "San Jone",
            "state": "CA",
            "postalCode": "394221"
        }
    },
   


{
    "firstName": "Apache",
    "lastName": "Spark",
    "gender": "Woman",
    "age": 24,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "5543",
        "city": "Queens",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "11372"
    }
}

]
```

This is the .json file I have, Once I created a dataframe, I need to separate the address into 4 columns.

Comment: i am usnig databricks, i think it's spark 3.0

Comment: you mentioned address is an array but looks like it struct type. you can use ```address.*``` it will create new columns as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------+
|address                   |
+--------------------------+
|[San Jone, 19422, CA, 126]|
|[Queens, 11372, NY, 5543] |
+--------------------------+
```

```
scala> val columns = Seq("city","zip","state","street").zipWithIndex
```

```
scala> df.select(columns.map(c => col(s"address")(c._2).as(c._1)):_*).show(false)
+--------+-----+-----+------+
|city    |zip  |state|street|
+--------+-----+-----+------+
|San Jone|19422|CA   |126   |
|Queens  |11372|NY   |5543  |
+--------+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: It gave this error: AnalysisException: Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0;

Comment: val columns = Seq("city","zip","state","street").zipWithIndex
test.select(columns.map(c => col(s"address")(c._2).as(c._1)):_*).show

Comment: I've edited the question if it makes it more clear. Please answer if you can. Thank You.